# how to display html file when clicks on list of links in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a blog website as a learning practice curve. I am giving a local file path name of each html file in the list. I use the map to create a list of links. When I click on created list of links, those links are broken and redirect to home page. How to fix this part of issue?

**Here is the Blog.js**

```
const BlogPath = ["./blog/blog1.js", "./blog/blog1.js", "./blog/blog1.js","./blog/blog1.js"];

BlogPath.map((Path, index) => 
      <div key={index}>
         <Link to={/Path}>{Path}</Link>
      </div>
)
```

**Here is the App.js**

```
function App() {

  return (
    <HashRouter >
      <ScrollToTop />
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation/>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={ <Home /> }/>
          <Route exact path="/blogList" element={<Blog />}/>
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>

    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

**I imported home and blog pages in App.js**

```
import Home from './Home.js';
import About from './Blog.js';
```

**Here is the Navigation.js**

```
   <>
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect sticky='top' expand='sm' variant='dark' className='background color '>
        <Container >
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav' />
          <Navbar.Collapse className='mobile-nav' id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
          <Nav className='me-auto'>
              <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/" >Home</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <Nav>
              <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/blogList" >Blog</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
```

Here is the sample: [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/admiring-kalam-lpxwel?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) **bold**

Comment: The `Link` component only links to paths you can defined as a `Route`. It appears you are trying to link to files instead, which is incorrect. What is this `"./blog/blog1.js"` file? Is it a React component? You should import these and render accordingly.

Comment: @DrewReese, `./blog/blog1.js` is a filepath. blog1.js has some content in it. I will be adding blog website every two weeks and assume I will have 100+ webpages and I have to import them all. Do I have to import all the files? if I have to then it's pain to import all the file one by one.

Comment: You may be able to dynamically import them by name... but your app would necessarily need to be aware of *what* it can import. Typically files like this would be served via an "backend" service. Your question at this point appears to be more about accessing these files and it does about routing and navigation. Do you have a more [complete and comprehensive code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @DrewReese, how to access to the files? Here is the sample: [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/admiring-kalam-lpxwel?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Ok, I see it in there now.

Comment: @DrewReese That's great to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `BlogList` component to render more reader/user-friendly paths.

```
function BlogList() {
  const BlogPath = ["blog1", "blog2", "blog1", "blog2", "blog3-4-5"];

  return (
    <>
      {BlogPath.map((path, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <Link to={path}>{path}</Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

This builds relative paths, i.e. `"/blogList/blog1"`

Add a route to the `App` to match and render this path:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div className="App background">
        <Navigation />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/blogList" element={<Bloglist />} />
          <Route path="/blogList/:blog" element={<Blog />} /> // <--

          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

Create a `Blog` component to read the `blog` route path param so it can dynamically/lazily load the matching blog file:

```
const Blog = () => {
  const { blog } = useParams();

  const [BlogItem, setBlogItem] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const BlogItem = React.lazy(() => import(`./blog/${blog}.js`));
    setBlogItem(BlogItem);
  }, [blog]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Blog</h1>
      {BlogItem && <BlogItem />}
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-display-html-file-when-clicks-on-list-of-links-in-react]

Comment: Everyday, I am learning something new from your response post. I wish you're my teacher!! I don't know what to say but thank you so much. For people who will see this post, please go and read his response  post and learn something new.